# Android - Draw a popup window in android mapView on a place

Tags: android, dictionary, popupwindow

I wanted to create a `popup` window on a place in `mapView`. I have seen some codes on net, but they are too complex to understand.
I just wanted to create a `popup` window on only a single place.

If you have code or link for this, then please share with me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are welling to use Maps V2 then you can find some sample code inside your android-sdk directory > extras > google > google_play_service > samples > maps

I believe you will find what you need in there